# Postgresql Error

Tags: postgresql, windows-server

I found below errors in  logs , Transaction stop logging in my database

```
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCERROR:  could not open file "base/16384/16464.3" (target block 858400): No such file or directory
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCSTATEMENT:  insert into jobqueue (jobtype,inum,params,submitted, nparam, sparam) values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCERROR:  could not open file "base/16384/16464.3" (target block 858467): No such file or directory
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCSTATEMENT:  insert into jobqueue (jobtype,inum,params,submitted, nparam, sparam) values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCERROR:  index "sessionstates_pk" is not a btree
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCSTATEMENT:  insert into sessionstates values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCERROR:  could not read block 381968 in file "base/16384/16464.2": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCSTATEMENT:  insert into jobqueue (jobtype,inum,params,submitted, nparam, sparam) values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCERROR:  index "sessionstates_pk" is not a btree
2019-11-19 15:48:25 UTCSTATEMENT:  insert into sessionstates values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
```

Comment: Did you disable your anti-virus software for the Postgres data directory?

Comment: No I didn't do any action

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from data corruption.

Perhaps someone deleted some files, perhaps your storage or file system isn't reliable, perhaps there are hardware problems, perhaps you did something to the database that you shouldn't have done.

In that case you should restore your last good backup.

But perhaps you are suffering from anti-virus software that randomly locks database files.

In that case you should keep the anti-virus software from accessing the PostgreSQL data directory.

Comment: On Windows, Anti-Virus software can also have that effect.

Comment: True; I didn't think of that. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Do you know The best way to recover this issue

Comment: Restore from a backup.